# How to update the a table with the values from table of another database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server Management Studio and quite newbie to SQL Server.

I have 2 databases, `Test1` and `Test2`. Both `Test1` and `Test2` have a table `Email` and they have the same design.

However, data in `Test2` is old, data in `Test1` is the latest.

What I want is to do is replace everything in `Test2.dbo.email` with the data from  `Test1.dbo.email`.

What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Test2.oldtable;

INSERT INTO Test2.oldTable (email, name, whatever) 
    SELECT email, name, whatever 
    FROM Test1.newtable
```

Answer (score 1):

In sql-server I always use `update T set ... from (select .. ) T`

because I can double check datas.

Script Like this:

```
update T
set email = newemail
from (
    select T1.email,T2.email newemail from Test1..email T1
    left join Test2..email T2 on T1.name = T2.name
    where T1.name is not null
) T
```